# Where to download JRockit for Java 7?

Tags: java, jrockit

I tried http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html but all I get is

> The content on this page is no longer available but your downloads may be found on the  Oracle Java Archive page.

Answer (score 9):

See [Java 7 Questions & Answers (circa 2011)](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_7_questions_answers):

> Q: When will JRockit be available for Java 7?
>
> A: It won't. As we
> explained last year we are merging JRockit and HotSpot into one single
> JVM. JDK 7 contains the first release of this converged JVM, where one
> of the first steps was to start removing the PermGen concept. Future
> JDK 7 updates will complete the PermGen removal, as well as add more
> visible features from JRockit.

Comment: Note that the PermGen was indeed removed, in JDK 8.

Answer (score -2):

Do also note that the commands in most cases just removed the R from JRockit commands.

JRCMD becomes JCMD

JRMC becomes JMC

- JRockit R28: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15061/toc.htm
- HotSpot 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/

Flight recording is even better because it - again - can make periodic thread dumps which had been removed in JRockit R28 but was available in JRockit R27.

The only feature I miss is JRockit Deterministic GC. But therefore we have an improved CMS collector and the G1 collector. Time will show whether this is a real alternative.

Comment: Where is the point? I just say that the tools are there but have different names. Flight recording is even better because it - again - can make periodic thread dumps which had been removed in JRockit R28 but was available in JRockit R27. The only feature I miss is JRockit Deterministic GC.