# Is JRockit merged into JDK 8?

Tags: jvm, java-8, jvm-hotspot, jrockit

There are many articles/webpages stating that JRockit will be merged into new version of JVM or JDK 8:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit

http://www.mythics.com/about/blog/answers-to-common-questions-on-java-versions-editions

[Where to download JRockit for Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578099/where-to-download-jrockit-for-java-7)

But I cannot find any articles/webpages stating that JRockit is really merged into JDK 8. Is there are any updated news for that? Or there is only part of the features of JRockit is implemented in JDK 8 so that the real-time performance of JDK 8 is not as good as JRockit? Thanks!

Comment: These virtual machines are already successfully merged. JDK 7 contains the first release of this converged JVM. There are two spaces open and proprietary. For example metaspace in open sourced, Mission Control and Flight Recorder are proprietary ones. Could you please clarify `the real-time performance of JDK 8 is not as good as JRockit`? It is a very controversial statement.

Comment: Full details on what features are non-free(mostly from JRockit) can be found in the product documentation http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html

Comment: Technically it is not a merge at all, but a reimplementation of the best features. Some of them are still WIP or not started, like deterministic GC (which I guess related to your real-time performance concerns), and the memory leak detector from JRMC

Answer (score 1):

From JDK 7 itself, JRockit and HotSpot has been merged into single JVM, incorporating the best features from both.

https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/oracles_jvm_strategy

Comment: Link mentioned above is not working and probably moved to other space thats why links are not appreciated over stack overflow.Thanks

Comment: Mirror courtesy of archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150420151920/https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/oracles_jvm_strategy